# How to get the path to an error in Joi 16 and above

Tags: javascript, joi

Previously there was a properly details where you could get the path to an error. This is important for us because we need to tell the user where in the document tree the error occurred rather than making them hunt for which leaf node had the issue.

```
error.details.map((detail) => {
    return `Error in node ${detail.path[0]}, child ${detail.path[1]}` 
}
```

Using joi 16+ I only get value and error back. Is there a way to retrieve the full tree to present this information?

Comment: In which `joi` version was the error details object still ok?

Comment: We were using joi 15.0.0 before breaking changes were introduced that removed this functionality